# JQuery: replace a string inside a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<div id="content">
...
<p>NUMBER times...</p>
...
<p>Place N°: NUMBER</p>
</div>
```

How do I replace all NUMBER inside the content div?
I tried `replace` method but it didn't work.

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use the standard Javascript replace function for strings.

```
oldhtml = $('div#content').html();
var newhtml = oldhtml.replace(/NUMBER/g, "123");
$('div.demo-container').html(newhtml);
```

Comment: Please be aware that replacing all the html content might affect existing attributes.

Answer (score 3):

You should iterate all your text nodes and replace the text inside them.

```
$('#content').children().each(function() {
 var textNode = $(this);
 textNode.text(textNode.text().replace("NUMBER", "NEW"));
});
```

This codes assumes all the children of #content just contain text.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('#content').children().each(function () {
    $(this).html(function (i, html) {
        return $(this).html().replace(/NUMBER/g, '123456');
    });
});
```