# How to get a:focus ~ .class css selector with jquery?

Tags: jquery

This is a simplified version of my html:

```
<li>
<a href="#" data-src="song Name.mp3">
<img src="front.jpg">Song Name.mp3</a>
<div class="hidden album">Album Name</div>
<div class="hoverdir">Path to album directory</div>
<div class="hidden artist">Artist Name</div>
</li>
```

At the moment if "a" has focus, .hoverdir is shown. I'm using:

```
.hoverdir {display: none;}    
a:focus ~ .hoverdir {display: block;}
```

in my css to achieve this and it's working fine.

I want to be able to replace some text contained in the hoverdir, but I can't figure out the right selector in jquery.

There are loads of these that are dynamically created that I need to replace part of the text in it if certain conditions are met. This one is just an example.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: There's no selector for this in jQuery. You'd need to use a `hover` or `focus` event handler, depending on what your desired behaviour is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working.
In my example, because the .hoverdir div is two elements below the "a" element I used:

```
$(this).next().next()
```

To find the .hoverdir div.

I used a technique from this question:
[JQuery: replace a string inside a div](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9448097/jquery-replace-a-string-inside-a-div)

```
oldhtml = $(this).next().next().html();
var newhtml = oldhtml.replace(/album/g, "");
$(this).next().next().html(newhtml);
```

not sure if it's the best way to do it but it works for my situation.

Comment: I know, but in my case the order will always be the same. I don't know why, but this is the only way I could get the result I needed. Your answer is the best way to do it for anyone else though.

Answer (score 1):

If you really want it through jquery you can use the following:

```
$("a").on("focus",function() {
  $(this).nextAll(".hoverdir").text("New TExt").show();
}).focusout(function() {
  $(this).nextAll(".hoverdir").hide();
})
```

**Demo**

```js
$("a").on("focus",function() {
  $(this).nextAll(".hoverdir").text("New TExt").show();
}).focusout(function() {
  $(this).nextAll(".hoverdir").hide();
})
```

```css
.hoverdir{
display:none;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
  <a href="#" data-src="song Name.mp3">
    <img src="front.jpg">Song Name.mp3</a>
  <div class="hidden album">Album Name</div>
  <div class="hoverdir">Path to album directory</div>
  <div class="hidden artist">Artist Name</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Thank you, but I have the show and hide covered with css. I want to be able to replace some text in the .hoverdir when it is shown.

Comment: @SimoneM Without knowing what element you want to replace the text of and from where the new text comes, I can only update it with an example. look at the code

Comment: I'm trying to replace the text in the hoverdirs. The hoverdir divs contains a path to the album folder for each song. For example "Audio/AlbumsVarious Artists/Album Name". I would like to be able to remove the Audio/Albums from the returned text.

Answer (score 1):

select the a when it has focus, find parent li tag, then find child with class  hoverdiv, replace text

```js
$("a").on("focus",function() {

$(this).parent("li").find(".hoverdir").text("replacement text");

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li>
<a href="#" data-src="song Name.mp3">
<img src="front.jpg">Song Name.mp3</a>
<div class="hidden album">Album Name</div>
<div class="hoverdir">Path to album directory</div>
<div class="hidden artist">Artist Name</div>
</li>
```

Comment: I have already tried this and I'm pretty sure this should work, but for some reason it isn't, I'll have a look throught the rest of my code and see if anything is stopping it

Comment: I know this should be working, but as I said I think the problem is somewhere else in my code, so i'll accept this as the answer. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to simply strip the `"Audio/Albums"` part from all `.hoverdir`, iterate over them when the DOM is parsed (`onDOMContentLoaded`). This is easy to do with Javascript only, no jQuery necessary for that.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  var hoverdirs = document.getElementsByClassName('hoverdir');

  for (var hoverdir of hoverdirs) {
    hoverdir.textContent = hoverdir.textContent.replace('Audio/Albums', '');
  }
})
```

```css
.hoverdir {
  display: none;
}

a[data-src]:hover ~ .hoverdir {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-src="song Name.mp3">
    Song Name.mp3</a>
    <div class="hidden album">Album Name</div>
    <div class="hoverdir">Audio/AlbumsVarious Artists/Album Name</div>
    <div class="hidden artist">Artist Name</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

You can exchange text via CSS as well:

```css
a[data-src] ~ .hoverdir::before {
  content: attr(data-text);
}

a[data-src]:hover ~ .hoverdir::before {
  content: attr(data-hover-text);
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>
    <a href="#" data-src="song Name.mp3">
    Song Name.mp3</a>
    <div class="hidden album">Album Name</div>
    <div class="hoverdir" data-text="Path to album directory" data-hover-text="Alternate text for link hover"></div>
    <div class="hidden artist">Artist Name</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Of course you would have to put the proper text in the data-attributes.

Comment: Thanks Connexo, That's very cool, I didn't know you could do that, but in my case there are loads of these dynamically created that I need to replace text in if certain conditions are met. The one in my question was just an example.

Comment: So it wouldn't work to simply iterate over all of the `.hoverdir` elements and replace the text? Why does it have to be on mouseover of that link?

Comment: This is for a search engine for the songs I have (thousands of them). I need it to work when the link to each song has focus, When focused the path to the directory the song is in is displayed, but there a few paths that I want to remove or replace some of the text in.

Answer (score 0):

Some CSS you have not provided and you indicate "show" but it IS shown so I make a broad assumption your `.hidden` CSS is `display:none` and use that class.  I added a "song" class just to aid in my visualization of the problem and use that on the link.

You did not indicate what you wished to do on focus out but I added that just to show how you might save the OLD text and restore it.

NOTE: no reason why you could not "pre adapt" it also - i.e. process all the changes with a `$("a.song").trigger('process');` on startup, so I have also shown that.

```js
$("a.song").on("focus process", function() {
  let hd = $(this).siblings(".hoverdir");
  //uncomment to save  hd.data("oldtext", hd.text());
  hd.text("New Text");
}).trigger('process');
/* uncomment to activate this
.on("focusout", function() {
  let hd = $(this).siblings(".hoverdir");
  let oldtext = hd.data("oldtext");
  console.log(oldtext);
  hd.text(oldtext);
});
*/
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}

a.song:focus~.hoverdir {
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>
    <a class="song" href="#" data-src="song Name.mp3">
      <img src="front.jpg">Song Name.mp3</a>
    <div class="hidden album">Album Name</div>
    <div class="hidden hoverdir">Path to album directory</div>
    <div class="hidden artist">Artist Name</div>
  </li>
  <li>
    <a class="song" href="#" data-src="song Name.mp3">
      <img src="front.jpg">Song Name.mp3</a>
    <div class="hidden album">Album Name</div>
    <div class="hidden hoverdir">Path2 to album directory</div>
    <div class="hidden artist">Artist Name</div>
  </li>
</ul>
```